# Change Hard Disk windows 7 to windows 10

Tags: hard-drive

My Computer Windows 10 pro i have only Totaly 78 GB Storage 
I need Add Second Hard Disk To my Computer... 
my old hard disk
but my old hard disk is windows 7
is there any problem to use windows 7 hard disk in windows 10 pro

Comment: No, not at all.

Comment: Are You Sure ?
Is there any problem?

Comment: Not if you use it for a storage drive.

Answer (score 0):

Your two alternatives are to overwrite the entire second hard drive and use it for storage or else shrink the Windows 7 partition and create a new partition on that that hard drive and use it for storage. If you choose the second option then shrink the Windows 7 hard drive from Windows 10, so you don't change the Windows 7 partition while it is actively running Windows 7. The default file system in Windows 7/10 is NTFS.